# General form to standard form regarding ellipse?

Tags: conic-sections, quadratic-programming

I've tried 2 hours to do this so I hope someone can help me:

$$11400000=-0.64x^2+2560x-y^2+6000y$$

It says that it have to equal an ellipse with center at the point $(2000,3000)$ and a horizontal semi-axis $a=500$ and a vertical semi-axis $b=400$

To prove that my teacher say I have turn the general form into the standard form.

I'm able to get the center at $(2000, 3000)$ but I don t get $a= 500$ and $b=400$

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things 
about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if 
you write what your thoughts 
are on the problem and include your efforts (work in progress) in 
this and future posts and in what context you have encountered the problem; this will prevent people 
from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers 
at the right level.
This site uses
[MathJax formatting](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need quadratic programming, just completing the square would suffice

$ -0.64x^2 + 2560x = -0.64(x^2 - 4000x) = -0.64(x^2 - 4000x + 2000^2 - 2000^2) = -0.64(x^2 - 4000x + 2000^2) + 0.64 \times 2000^2 = -0.64(x - 2000)^2 + 2560000 $

$ - y^2 + 6000y = -1(y^2 - 6000y) = -1(y^2 - 6000y + 3000^2 - 3000^2) = -1(y^2 - 6000y + 3000^2)  + 3000^2 = -(y - 3000)^2 + 9000000 $

Therefore we have

$ 11400000=-0.64x^2+2560x-y^2+6000y $

$ 11400000 = (-0.64(x - 2000)^2 + 2560000) + (-(y - 3000)^2 + 9000000) $

$ 0.64(x - 2000)^2 + (y - 3000)^2 = 160000 $

$ \frac{0.64(x - 2000)^2}{160000} + \frac{(y - 3000)^2}{160000} = 1 $

$ \frac{(x - 2000)^2}{500^2} + \frac{(y - 3000)^2}{400^2} = 1 $

Comment: Thank you so much! I found my mistake and I get it know!